# Java: Unregister listeners in Closeable.close()

Tags: java

I sometimes have to write objects that register themselves as listeners onto other objects.
Good programming practices say that we should always unregister such listeners.
Is it a good practice to try to enforce such behaviour by making the class implement `Closeable` and unregister the listener inside `close()` ?

I thought that Closeable was meant mainly to close OS resources (e.g. files..) and I'm not sure if the listener case goes out the scope of Closeable's responsibility.

Comment: this would imply that the listener would know how to unregister itself, and keep track of everywhere it is registered.

Answer (score 2):

There is some level of opinion here, but based on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and the name of the method `close`, I would create a different method for it (and call it `unregister`). The reason is that you want the code to be as much self-explanatory as possible.

Also note the documentation on `close()` itself:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it. If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

Based on the code you describe, there is no such stream or system resource.

**EDIT:**

BTW, it seems in case you want to go with the `Closeable` solution, a better way is to implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) instead since it would allow you to use try-with-resources in the code that uses these listeners. In the documentation of `AutoCloseable`, the following is mentioned:

> **API Note:**
>
> **It is possible, and in fact common, for a base class to implement AutoCloseable even though not all of its subclasses or instances will hold releasable resources.** For code that must operate in complete generality, or when it is known that the AutoCloseable instance requires resource release, it is recommended to use try-with-resources constructions. However, when using facilities such as Stream that support both I/O-based and non-I/O-based forms, try-with-resources blocks are in general unnecessary when using non-I/O-based forms.

This note implies that a class *may* implement `AutoCloseable` even if its implementation does not use actual resources. However, the note also suggests that there should be at least one subclass (in your case, at least one type of listener) that does use actual resources. Such is the case with the `Stream` API.

Comment: I agree, but why do we need to create another interface? The average Java developer knows about `Closeable` and knows how to act when dealing with closeable objects.
Creating another interface or an `unregister()` method just adds complexity to the API.

Comment: @MarcoRomano I expanded the answer a bit. If none of the listener subclasses uses resources, I would still create a separate interface for them. I would still favor readability against re-using something that already exists, but which does not really apply exactly to my case.

Comment: `Autocloseable` being a super-interface of `Closeable`, it is ok to implement either one of them. A try-with-resources will work in both cases. Closeable has stronger constraints about the idempotence of the method `#close()` and a more specific exception. Otherwise, the two are equivalent.